# UIAlertControllerTitle title is not responsive?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

My app is responsive, If alert is showing and user increases the font size, font size of alert message is increasing but font size of alert title is not increasing. I am using below code to display the UIAlertController.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

//Swift 2.0
let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: deleteBtnText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: deleteHandler)
alert.addAction(deleteAction)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelBtnText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: cancelHandler)
alert.addAction(cancelAction)

// Set light teal color for alert tint color
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.LTColor()
// set background color for text
let dictTitleColor = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.LTColor()]
let titleAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title, attributes: dictTitleColor)
alert.setValue(titleAttributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
UIUtils.stopIndicator()

if let presented = appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController {
    presented.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//Swift 2.0 by Nikhil
// Set light teal color for alert tint color
alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.LTColor()
return alert
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using attributed string to set alert title that’s why your font remain the same. 
You can change it in your dictTitleColor with the NSAttributedStringKey.font.

Comment: If I set the font property. Alert is already showing and user change the font, will it get reflect??

Comment: How are you changing the font size?

Comment: in iPhone : Setting -> General -> Accessibility -> LargerText